# ORACLE SQL CSV Column comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a table with CSV values as column. I want use that column in where clause to compare subset of CSV is present or not. For example Table has values like

```
1| 'A,B,C,D,E'
```

Query:

select id from tab where **csv_column contains 'A,C'**;

This query should return 1.

How to achieve this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this using `LIKE`, making sure to search for the three types of pattern for each letter/substring which you intend to match:

```
SELECT id
FROM yourTable
WHERE (csv_column LIKE 'A,%' OR csv_column LIKE '%,A,%' OR csv_column LIKE '%,A')
      AND
      (csv_column LIKE 'C,%' OR csv_column LIKE '%,C,%' OR csv_column LIKE '%,C')
```

Note that match for the substring `A` means that either `A,`, `,A,` or `,A` appears in the CSV column.

We could also write a structurally similar query using `INSTR()` in place of `LIKE`, which might even give a peformance boost over using wildcards.

Comment: you need some brackets in there otherwise the AND will not work as intended

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

there's probably something funky you can do with regular expressions but in simple terms...  if A and C will always be in that order

```
csv_column LIKE '%A%C%'
```

otherwise

```
(csv_column LIKE '%A%' AND csv_column LIKE '%C%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to edit your search string, this could be a way:

```
select *
from yourTable
where csv like '%' || replace('A,C', ',', '%') || '%'
```

For example:

```
with yourTable(id, csv) as (
  select 1, 'A,B,C,D,E' from dual union all
  select 2, 'A,C,D,E'   from dual union all
  select 3, 'B,C,D,E'   from dual 
)
select *
from yourTable
where csv like '%' || replace('A,C', ',', '%') || '%'
```

gives:

```
        ID CSV
---------- ---------
         1 A,B,C,D,E
         2 A,C,D,E
```

Consider that this will only work if the characters in the search string have the same order of the CSV column; for example:

```
with yourTable(id, csv) as (
  select 1, 'C,A,B' from dual 
)
select *
from yourTable
here csv like '%' || replace('A,C', ',', '%') || '%'
```

will give no results

Answer (score 0):

Why not store the values as separate columns, and then use simple predicate filtering?